# Wordpress Admin ajax request return value with 0 when echo outside of the function

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, return

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results' );

function ybr_client_results() {
    $client_details = $_POST[ 'client_details' ];
    return $client_details;
    die();
}
 echo ybr_client_results();
```

it returns value with 0. how to fix it.

Comment: What's the reason why you should echo the ajax function outside it is supposed to be called from ajax script. I also suggest you use the WordPress function wp_die();

Comment: Yes, that echo makes no sense at all... look for `wp_send_json_success` and `wp_send_json_error` functions

Comment: i just want to pass this $client_details variable value to fetch data from database

Answer (score 1):

**You can try the below following snippet to fetech data from database and encode it by using json_encode() and then call wp_die()**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results' );

function ybr_client_results() {

   $client_details = $_POST[ 'client_details' ];

   $result = getPosts();

   echo json_encode($result, true);

    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly registered an AJAX callback; the code will execute when the AJAX action is triggered. The function shouldn't be echoed.

There are a couple of issues with the callback itself:

- It's returning a variable rather than generating output
- There's a return statement above `die()` so that line is never reached

Corrected version:

```
function ybr_client_results() {
    /**
     * I've left this unaltered for the sake of answering the question at hand.
     *
     * Don't forget to check the value exists and sanitize it correctly.
     */
    $client_details = $_POST['client_details'];

    // This AJAX callback needs to output something, not return.
    echo $client_details;

    // As another user mentioned, there's a WP specific die function.
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ybr_client_results', 'ybr_client_results' );
```

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: i just want to pass this $client_details variable value to fetch data from database

Comment: The above code should resolve your initial question or at least all of the flaws in the code posted as part of that question. Once you have the value from JS in your AJAX callback, it's down to you to treat it in any way you like.